# Tkinter: How do I clear the window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So this program asks for a name and last name. I'm looking for the program to clear and show "Welcome " + name + " " + lastname.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def salir():
    sys.exit()

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Matricula UTEC')
Label(root, text = "Bienvenido a Matricula UTEC").grid(row = 0)
Label(root, text = "Ingrese sus nombres: ").grid(row = 1)
Label(root, text = "Ingrese sus apellidos: ").grid(row = 2)
e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=1, column = 1)
e2.grid(row=2, column = 1)
Button(root, text = 'Salir', command = salir).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 4)
Button(root, text = 'Comenzar', command = salir).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 4)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to put everything you want to "clear" in a frame. Then, you can simply delete the frame and replace it with a different frame.

Here's a really simple example:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def salir():
    login_frame.destroy()
    home_frame = home()
    home_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def login():
    frame = Frame(root)
    Label(frame, text = "Bienvenido a Matricula UTEC").grid(row = 0)
    Label(frame, text = "Ingrese sus nombres: ").grid(row = 1)
    Label(frame, text = "Ingrese sus apellidos: ").grid(row = 2)
    e1 = Entry(frame)
    e2 = Entry(frame)
    e1.grid(row=1, column = 1)
    e2.grid(row=2, column = 1)
    Button(frame, text = 'Salir', command = salir).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 4)
    Button(frame, text = 'Comenzar', command = salir).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 4)
    return frame

def home():
    frame = Frame(root)
    Label(frame, text="Welcome").pack()
    return frame

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Matricula UTEC')

login_frame = login()
login_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you add variables, such as e1, e2 (name, lastname) to a label?